# I forgot to add internet access in my app

Tags: flutter, dart, google-play, google-play-console

I uploaded my app to Google Play Console and it has been under review for a day and a half, but I forgot to add this code to the file

```
<manifest xmlns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <application ...
</manifest>
```

What should I do now, should I wait for the application to be accepted and update it, or is there a way to update it while it is in the review stage?

and Will it be accepted or rejected, knowing that the application contains Firebase databases?

Answer (score 1):

Turn managed publishing off (if not already) and submit an update with needed changes. This way the faulty package is never published and eventually replaced with the update package.

See [Control when app changes are published with managed publishing](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859654?hl=en)

Comment: They said:
Your app must already be available to use managed publishing. You can’t use it when publishing an app for the first time.

and this my first app.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry, your will get rejected because it will not work properly without internet ( I am using your app required internet to use). So after rejection you can upload new build with internet permission.